# The indefinite article – does local pronunciation change when I should use a/an

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-articles

I have a question about how different pronunciation of words and how this affects the use of indefinite articles.

My example is the technical abbreviation URL, meaning "uniform resource location". A common way to pronounce it is "you-are-ell", and to use the indefinite article **a** because of the consonant "y". -- [Which is correct — a URL or an URL?](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/writing-for-business/which-is-correct-a-url-or-an-url/)

However, since it is an abbreviation, I have always pronounced it word-by-word "u-are-ell", and I have used the indefinite article **an** with this word.

I would like to extend this question to any word that have a different pronunciation as there are many different dialects.

Is it accepted to chose the indefinite article (a or an) based on how **you** pronounce a word?

Comment: I don't know of any dialects that would enunciate URL as OO-ARE-ELL - it's always YOU-ARE-ELL, which according to standard rules would always be preceded by ***a***, not ***an***.

Comment: URL is not perhaps the best example - since my native tongue is not english, I tend to spell letters in my own language - at least the U.

But please move away from my bad example. What I am curious about is, if a word starts with a vowel in one dialect, but consonant in another - what would be the correct article?

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld - Here is the best explanation I could find online addressing this issue: http://wordinfo.info/unit/3431/ip:1 It has many examples I hadn't thought of; e.g., a eulogy, a union, a European, a one-time event, an hour, an honor, an honest person, an heir; but, a hotel, a house, a hill, a hymn, a honeycomb, etc.  As for your question, "Is it acceptable to choose the indefinite article (a or an) based on how **you** pronounce a word?" I would say the answer is "yes" when speaking and "no" when writing. When writing, use the convention used by your audience.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of dialects, there will tend to be one "official" pronunciation of any word, and you should base your decision on this.

I don't actually understand what the difference in pronunciation between  "you-are-ell" and "u-are-ell" would be: saying that you pronounce "U" as "u" is totally redundant and doesn't tell us anything.

If you are *speaking*, rather than writing, you *could* use "a" or "an" depending on how you pronounce it, but I'd still recommend pronouncing it in the "conventional" way, just for the sake of clearer communication.

Comment: Many words have several pronunciations. It's really rare that these change whether you need *a* or *an* before them, though—the only ones I can think of are *herb*, *opossom* and *Ouroboros*, all of which have been discussed in questions here.